# How to wear eye protection if you already wear glasses?

Tags: protection

I wear glasses with relatively large frames (due to the shape of my face, smaller frames don't really work). I'm nearsighted and can't see without them. Unfortunately many safety goggles don't fit at all on top of my glasses, and the few that do are still offset too much from my face and allow debris to come in easily from the bottom.

Is there a better solution for eye protection, if you already have to wear glasses?

- Pretending that my prescription glasses are eye protection won't work. See [slide 8 in this presentation](https://www.slideshare.net/gauthamsankaraselvam/personal-protective-equipment-whats-it-all-about).
- Most safety glasses that do fit over glasses protect inadequate protection from debris flying up from below.
- Contacts are probably a bad idea, because they create additional risks from chemical fumes and getting dust in your contacts is really not fun.

Comment: This site has restrictions about product recommendations, so read this fast... Bolle Vigilante with Bolle's Sport Optic rx insert. Caveat: they are not ansi certified, but they share the basic attributes of safety glasses.

Comment: Are you looking for debris/impact protection, chemical/splash protection, or both? And there is such a thing as prescription safety glasses...

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest getting prescription safety glasses. If the cost is unreasonable wear your regular glasses with a face-shield. Face-shields offer maximum protection they are however prone to fogging up in humid areas.

Comment: And you can get side shields that go around the safety classes that prevent the intrusions. https://www.northernsafety.com/safety/safety-products/eye-protection/safety-glasses-accessories-signs/sideshields

Answer (score 3):

The best solution is to buy prescription safety glasses.  There are many possible sources - just google the term.

Comment: Be sure to get large enough lenses. The small frames may not protect you from something bouncing off your eyebrows, or coming in at an angle.